# I am getting an a "TypeError" when trying to add a item to the database in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to add an item in the database but I keep getting the TypeError, what am i doing wrong please. I have the model class for it and I am using the Django ModelForm to implement the Create operation.

Error Log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Alex_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Alex_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Alex_SMS\SMS\core\views.py", line 26, in Addproduct
    form = Addproduct()

Exception Type: TypeError at /add-product/
Exception Value: Addproduct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class Addproduct(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def Addproduct(request):

    form = Addproduct()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addproduct(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Products Added Successfully")
            return redirect('product')

    context = {"form":form}

    return render(request, "core/addstation.html", context)
```

Comment: Your views name is **also** `Addproduct`. you basically call that instead of your form...

Comment: Thanks Sir. I will correct it.

Comment: can you help with this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294537/i-have-getting-wrong-values-after-perrforming-some-arithmetic-in-django-views-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the view the *same* name as the form, so if you call `Addproduct`, it will call the view, since the view overwrote the reference to the form.

I suggest that you *rename* your form to:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

#          ↓ rename to …Form
class AddproductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

and update the view with:

```
def add_product(request):

    form = AddproductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddproductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Products Added Successfully')
            return redirect('product')

    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'core/addstation.html', context)
```

Normally function-based views are written in `snake_case`, so `add_product` instead of <s>`AddProduct`</s>.

Comment: can you please help with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294537/i-have-getting-wrong-values-after-perrforming-some-arithmetic-in-django-views-an